# How to update meta value using update_user_meta in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have already created a meta_key named "etime" for storing students' preferred time of attending online exams. The field is created by a function in my child theme's function.php file and the field is accepting inputs from the registration form of my site.

Now I need to include the same field in the  edit-user.php file of WordPress to enable the students to edit their time preference.

I tried with this code, but it doesn't work. It doesn't update the meta_value against the meta_key "etime".

```
<select name="newetime">
    <option value="9">6 am - 9 am</option>
    <option value="12">9 am - 12 noon</option>
    <option value="15">12 noon - 3 pm</option>
    <option value="18">3 pm - 6 pm</option>
    <option value="21">6 pm - 9 pm</option>
    <option value="24">9 pm - 12 am</option>
</select>

<?php
$etime = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'etime', true);
$newetime = $_POST['newetime'];
update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'etime', $etime); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the start of your PHP

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

Or use `get_current_user_id()` in place of `$current_user->ID`

**The dropdown**

To display the current option in your dropdown you need to do:

```
<?php $etime = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'etime', true); ?>
<select name="newetime">
    <option value="9" <?php selected( $etime, 9 ); ?>>6 am - 9 am</option>
    <option value="12" <?php selected( $etime, 12 ); ?>>9 am - 12 noon</option>
    <option value="15" <?php selected( $etime, 15 ); ?>>12 noon - 3 pm</option>
    <option value="18" <?php selected( $etime, 18 ); ?>>3 pm - 6 pm</option>
    <option value="21" <?php selected( $etime, 21 ); ?>>6 pm - 9 pm</option>
    <option value="24" <?php selected( $etime, 24 ); ?>>9 pm - 12 am</option>
</select>
```

**A security consideration**

Hackers can send whatever data they want as the newetime. It's probably best to cast it to an int.

```
$newetime = (int)$_POST['newetime'];
```

And then you won't even have to worry about receiving dirty data.